# What are the implication of using iommu=force in the boot kernel options?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iommu

I have to follow a hardening procedure for a linux os, in this procedure it tels us that the kernel option must have `iommu=force`.

What does it do ? What could be the difference without specifying anything about iommu? Is it compatible with the pci pass-through where I have set `intel_iommu=on`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, these options complement each other, specifically, `iommu` manages the use of this technology in the system, the `force` value ensures that it will always be used no matter what; and `intel_iommu` is the technology itself, an IOMMU specification (Intel VT-d), just as there is one for AMD (AMD-Vi) `amd_iommu`.

Just analyze the following configuration options:

General `iommu` (input/output memory management unit) options:

> `off`
> Don't initialize and use any kind of IOMMU.

> `noforce`
> Don't force hardware IOMMU usage when it is not needed. (**default**).

> `force`
> Force the use of the hardware IOMMU even when it is not actually needed (e.g. because < 3 GB memory).

> `soft`
> Use software bounce buffering (SWIOTLB) (**default for Intel machines**). This can be used to **prevent** the usage of an available hardware IOMMU.

Now, Intel IOMMU:

> `intel_iommu` [DMAR] Intel IOMMU driver (DMAR) option

DMAR: Direct Memory Access Remapping

> `on`
> Enables the Intel IOMMU Driver.

There are more options for `intel_iommu` (`off`, `igfx_off`, `forcedac`, ...), but they are not relevant to this question.

I am not a specialist in this topic, perhaps I am missing something, so here are some sources:

- [IOMMU Introduction](https://terenceli.github.io/%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF/2019/08/04/iommu-introduction)
- [Intel IOMMU Driver Analysis](https://terenceli.github.io/%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF/2019/08/10/iommu-driver-analysis)
- [Intel Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/c5/15/vt-directed-io-spec.pdf)
- [Boot Options](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/boot-options.txt)
- [Kernel parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)
- [Understanding the IOMMU Linux grub File Configuration](https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/understanding-the-iommu-linux-grub-file-configuration)

Comment: why `< 3 GB memory`, not `< 4 GB memory`?

Comment: @陳力 Good question, I tried to find an explanation without success. Although I found some very old posts (from 2005) with the following errors (for upgrading to 4GB of RAM): 
   `PCI-DMA not syncing: high address but no IOMMU`    
`Kernel panic: PCI-DMA: high address but not IOMMU` 
`PCI-DMA: More than 4GB of RAM and no IOMMU` 
`PCI-DMA: 32bit PCI IO may malfunction. <6> PCI DMA: disabling IOMMU` 
[1](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/pci-dma-not-syncing-high-address-but-no-iommu-289298/) [2](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=169115)

Answer (score 3):

Both `iommu` and `intel_iommu` are Lx `grub` parameters, mainly for SR-IOV pass-through (pt) mode.

- `iommu=force`
  Forces the use of the hardware IOMMU  ("Input Output Memory Management Unit") even when it is not actually needed (e.g. because < 3 GB memory). How does this hardens your runtime?

Well behaved drivers call pci_map_*() calls before sending command to device that needs to perform DMA. Once DMA is completed and mapping is no longer required, device performs a pci_unmap_*() calls to unmap the region. The Intel IOMMU driver allocates a virtual address per domain. Each PCIE device is forced to have its own domain (hence the protection).

- `intel_iommu=on`
  Just enables SR-IOV in the kernel.

Note that to get the best performance, add `iommu=pt` (pass-through) to the `grub` file when using SR-IOV. When in pass-through mode, the adapter does not need to use DMA translation to the memory, and this improves the performance. `iommu=pt` is needed mainly when hypervisor performance is needed.  Look [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/IOMMU_SWIOTLB) and [that](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/Intel-IOMMU.txt) up for background info.

In this example, your `grub` file could look like something like this:

```
kernel /vmlinuz-Ub15.10x86_64-5.5.15-42-generic root=/dev/sda1 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 rhgb intel_iommu=on iommu=pt
```

HTH

Comment: Ok, so using force makes it more secure, but could be slower than using pt ?

Comment: Sorry, I will read the links that you have provided, I really want to understand what does it means, but at the same times I must find a « simple » way to explain it to coworkers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not to necropost, but I thought giving a concise answer would be good.  As Cbhihe says above, the driver will allocate or set aside some DMA memory, and tell the device to use it.  But this is really a suggestion, the device can (either due to bugs or maliciously) actually use DMA to read and write any system memory it wants to (this includes naughty USB3 and Thunderbolt devices being able to potentially read out your system memory, although I think some newer USB3 and Thunderbolt controllers can block this on their own).  iommu dmar (DMA Remapping) blocks these improper DMA accesses, and iommu=force makes sure it's turned on to do so. A prudent precaution for a secured system.